# How do I get the `pivot table` model to trigger the save/saved model events when attach or detach are called in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4 how do I get the `pivot table` model to trigger the save/saved model events when attach or detach are called?

It seems that the pivot table 'TeamUser' below is not actually needed for the attach/detach methods to work, so at a guess I believe that the model representing the pivot table is never invoked. And so the events are never triggered.

To ask another way:
When I call `User::with('Team')->find(1)->teams()->attach(1);` how to get `TeamUser` to trigger it's own events. Note that the above attach works perfectly fine, all the records are updated in the database.

**User**

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    // Relationship
    public function teams() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Team');
    }    
}
```

**Team**

```
class Team extends Eloquent 
{
    // Relationship
    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }    
}
```

**Team User** - The model for the `TeamUser` table/pivot table

```
class TeamUser extends Eloquent 
{
    public function save(array $options = array())
    {
        // do cool stuff when relationship is saved via
        // attach/detach
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `$touches` to the Team model.

```php
class Team extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $touches = array('TeamUser');

    // Relationship
    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }    
}
```

This will update the TeamUser `updated_at` field. I think this will also hit the `save()` method in the TeamUser model.

If that doesn't work, you can fire your own event in the Team `save()` method and listen to this event somewhere.

```php
Event::fire('team.updated', array($team));
```

Comment: When Team touches TeamUser, that doesn't mean the attach() or detach() is called. When Team::save() is fired, neither does it mean that the attach() or detach() is called. Why is this answer accepted? I'm searching for a solution as well, but this imo isn't it.

Comment: @RonaldHulshof you can listen to pivot table for updated, and this will make sure that .updated will fire

Answer (score 3):

With the new version of Laraval 5.8, Pivot tables trigger the boot events. Check the release notes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases#pivot

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I was looking exactly for this.